# How to call controller method on click of tab in liferay ui tabs?

Tags: tabs, liferay, liferay-6

I am using liferay ui tabs in my project. I would like to call the controller on click of the tabs. I used portlerURL attribute for try but its not working.

**Here is my code snippet :-**

**view.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/portlet" prefix="liferay-portlet"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="liferay-theme"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>


<liferay-theme:defineObjects />
<portlet:defineObjects />


<liferay-portlet:renderURL var="portletURL" />

<%
    //We must Specify a default value for tabs. In this example it is sunday. Else it //will throw an error.
    String tabValue = ParamUtil.getString(request, "tab", "sunday");
    String tabsURL = "/" + tabValue.trim() + ".jsp";
    String tabNames = "Sunday,Monday,Tuesday";
    String tabVal = "sunday,monday,tuesday";
    if (permissionChecker.isCompanyAdmin(themeDisplay.getCompanyId())) {
        tabNames += ",Admin";
        tabVal += ",admin";
    }

    PortletURL URL = renderResponse.createActionURL();
    URL.setParameter("click","tabClick");
%>

<liferay-ui:tabs names="<%=tabNames%>" tabsValues="<%=tabVal%>" param="tab" url="<%= portletURL %>" />

<c:import url="<%= tabsURL %>"></c:import>
```

**Controller :-**

```
import com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;

import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;

/**
 * Portlet implementation class TabDemoPortlet
 */
public class TabDemoPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

    public void sunday(ActionRequest req,ActionResponse res) {
        System.out.println("Hello Sunday!!!");
    }

    public void monday(ActionRequest req,ActionResponse res) {
        System.out.println("Hello Monday!!!");
    }

    public void tuesday(ActionRequest req,ActionResponse res) {
        System.out.println("Hello Tuesday!!!");
    }
}
```

All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Just a little addition: That url attribute in the tag is for renderURL and in the render method you can check which tab was clicked by fetching the param from the request with the tab-name you have entered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create multiple actionURLs and use them in you liferay-ui:tabs. Some thing like this

```
<portlet:actionURL name="sunday" var ="sundayURL"/>
<portlet:actionURL name="monday" var ="mondayURL"/>
<portlet:actionURL name="tuesday" var ="tuesdayURL"/>

<liferay-ui:tabs names="<%=tabNames%>" 
   url0="<%=sundayURL/>"
   url1="<%=mondayURL/>"
   url2="<%=tuesdayURL/>"/>
```